# Add <a> elemnt in <li> element with append

Tags: jquery

I have a loop and in this loop I will add `li` element and after that I should add `a` element inside `li` , but when I wrote this code, the `a` element will add to all `li` elements.

```
var toolbarArray = new Array("Home", "About", "Contact");
var ceItem = $('#toolbar').append('<ul></ul>').find('ul');
var ceLiItem;
for (i=0; i<toolbarArray.length; i++) {
    ceLiItem = ceItem.append('<li></li>').find('li');
    ceLiItem.append('<a>'+toolbarArray[i]+'</a>');
}
```

this is result: http://jsfiddle.net/SKPxE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your code can be re-arranged a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/SKPxE/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var toolbarArray = new Array("Home", "About", "Contact"),
        toolbar = $('<ul></ul>').appendTo('#toolbar');

    $.each(toolbarArray, function(i,o) {
        var link = $('<a></a>').attr('href','').text(o),
            celItem = $('<li></li>').append(link);
        toolbar.append(celItem);
    });   
});​
```

1. declaring just one `var` per scope makes things a little neater (jsLint).
2. you can use `$.each()` to iterate an array (your method is fine too, but there will be times when the jQ version will come in handy
3. your link will most likely be more than just text, so the code above prepares you for that (note the `href` attribute)
4. when you create an element with jquery, `$('<li></li>')`, you do not need to use `.find()` to grab it, it's already there
5. **edit:** see Anthony's post on `.appendTo()`

Comment: sorry I have a question in your code, what's mean of i in function (i,o) ?

Comment: `i` is the index of the array, and `o` is the element.  You can name those two variables anything you want: [jquery $.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.appendTo()` so you don't have to call `.find()` to get a jQuery object that refers to the object you just added (and, more than likely, a lot of other `<ul>` or `<li>` elements), like so:

```
var toolbarArray = new Array("Home", "About", "Contact");
var ceItem = $('<ul></ul>').appendTo('#toolbar');
var ceLiItem;
for (i=0; i<toolbarArray.length; i++) {
    ceLiItem = $('<li></li>').appendTo(ceItem);
    ceLiItem.append('<a>'+toolbarArray[i]+'</a>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var toolbarArray = new Array("Home", "About", "Contact");
var ceItem = $('#toolbar').append('<ul></ul>').find('ul');
var ceLiItems = '';
for (i=0; i<toolbarArray.length; i++) {
    var ceLiItems+= '<li><a>'+toolbarArray[i]+'</a></li>'
}
ceItem.append(ceLiItems);
```

This code is more efficient and fast as it will save a number of useless DOM traversals.

Answer (score 0):

this is better

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var toolbarArray = new Array("Home", "About", "Contact");

    var ceList = $('<ul></ul>');
    $('#toolbar').append(ceList);

    $.each(toolbarArray, function(index, value) {
        ceList.append('<li><a>' + value + '</a></li>');
    });
});
```